# What is this vehicle?

Tags: 4wd, vehicle-identification

I just took a picture of this on my way home. I'm a long time car enthusiast, I've raced legally in several formats, I'm a big time 4wd enthusiast, Moab and very technical trails in Colorado for example, but have no clue what on earth this is. 2 doors, lifted, legit beadlock tires and a rear tire carrying bumper. Not sure if this is the correct place to post this, so apologies if not, but seriously, WTF is this awesome piece of steel?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Haha! One mistake! Who knows if it *actually steel* :o) Just playing! Yes, vehicle ID questions are on topic for this Stack. I know I've seen this before and am trying to place it. I'm sure somebody has a clue!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a [local motors rally fighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rally_Fighter).

Comment: It sure does. I thought it was the G-tec from the other answer, but that molding on the door is a spot on match.

Comment: Yah, on 2nd thought ... I'm thinking you're right, lol.

Comment: My previous answer, now deleted (that the pictured car is a G-Tec X-Road (originally Sandracer 500GT) is wrong, and user71525 is correct - this is a Local Motors Rally Fighter. They sure do look alike.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - I'm glad you posted that regardless, that is an awesome vehicle.